# Imported .nc rasters not editable in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, editing, netcdf

I imported .nc files from the OB.DAAC website and used the make NetCDF a new raster tool in ArcGIS Pro. These show up fine but they are not editable.

I right clicked on the geodatabase and added a new feature layer and it showed up under the gdb but I have no idea what to do with that or how to fix this problem.

So basically I have 2 rasters of the whole US of chlorophyll data. I only want to focus on the east coast of FL. One raster is from 2004 during a red tide bloom and the other is from 2010 where is was normal. All I want to do is create two rasters of just that coastal spot and compare the difference in chlorophyll amount. When I used extract by mask just now I may have put the whole rasters in the wrong spot but it created a layer that's greyscale and doesn't show up as anything when I turn all other layers off.

[image]

Comment: Rasters are a very different data structure to vector (feature) datasets. I recommend you edit your question to include full details or links to the the netcdf (.nc) data and some information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have never edited a raster, only vector data. What are you trying to do?